# what causes the org.xml.sax.saxparseexception: already seen doctype

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xpath

I am using Eclipse to find a specific anchor elements in XML file. The plugin I am using in Eclipse is XPath. When I typed in the element I want to find, it shows:

> org.xml.sax.saxparseexception: already seen doctype

```
<div class="list">
<input name = "abc" type = "hidden" value = "true">
...
```

and if I want to search all the attribute `name`. I type in `//@name` in the expression field. it shows the error warning like that. Did I typed in the wrong expression or any ways find the element? Thanks

Comment: A doctype nodes looks like `<!DOCTYPE html>`, the error message sounds as if the parser finds two of them in your input sample. So we need to see the beginning of your XML or you need to check yourself whether there is more than one such node in the input.

Comment: @Martin Honnen thanks! the xml file indeed starts with `<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "" "">` but it is generated automatically using JTidy, if I change it manually to `<?xml version="1.0"?>` it's still happens...any suggestion to solve it? thanks so much!

Comment: An XML document is only allowed a single DOCTYPE node or none at all, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-prolog. If a tool like JTidy creates two of them then it is broken or you are not using the right settings to have it output well-formed XML. As I am not familiar with JTidy I can't help with that. If you remove the two DOCTYPE nodes manually then I can't understand why you would still get the error message about doctype, that does not make sense to me. You might want to post a minimal but complete XML document for which Eclipse gives an error, then perhaps some with Eclipse can reproduce it